# How to split array values, group by first substring, and combine second substring values?

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I am working on sencha and php. The data return from sencha as an array:

```
$permissionArr = Array([0] =>1_2 ,[1] =>"1_3", [2] =>1_4, [3] =>2_3, [4] =>"2_4",[5] =>"2_5");
```

I want to create an array using the values of above array.

```
array[
    [0]=>[
       'moduleId' => 1,
       'permission' => '2,3,4'
    ]
]
```

I tried to solve, but I think I am not following the correct way.

```
$permissionArr = Array("0" =>1 ,"1" =>"1_3", "2" =>2, "3" =>3, "4" =>"3_1","5" =>"3_2","6" =>4,"7" =>"4_1"); 
$finalArr = array();
foreach($permissionArr as $key => $value) {                     
    if(stristr( $value, '_') ){
        array_push($finalArr, $value);
    } 
} 
$aa = array();
foreach($finalArr as $key => $val){
    $permissionArray = explode( '_', $val); 
    array_push($aa, $permissionArray);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please edit the question and fix all the errors you have in there? If you want quality answers, then make sure your question has a minimum level of quality too. Currently there are unquoted literals, curly quotes which makes this invalid PHP.  Then add the code you tried with (if you don't have any, then try first), and pinpoint where you bumped into a problem.

Comment: Use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) with `key=>value` loop to get all elements of `$permissionArr` and use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the permission strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php

$permissionArr = array("0" =>1 ,"1" =>"1_3", "2" => "1_4", "3" => "3", "4" =>"3_1","5" =>"3_2","6" =>"4","7" =>"4_1");

$groupedPermArr = array_reduce(
    $permissionArr,
    function ($output, $value) {
        $values = explode('_', $value);

        $output[$values[0]]['module_id'] = $values[0];

        if (isset($values[1])) {
            $output[$values[0]]['permission'][] = $values[1];
        }

        return $output;
    },
    []
);

$stringifiedPermArr = array_map(
    function ($value) {
        $value['permission'] = implode(',', array_unique($value['permission']));

        return $value;
    },
    $groupedPermArr
);

var_dump($stringifiedPermArr);
```

Explanation:
1. Firstly create an array of arrays with keys "module_id" and "permission".
2. Secondly iterate over this array, make sure that permissions are unique and join them with separator.

Comment: Good answer - you separate the grouping and the presentation logic rather than using a single loop

Comment: Why is that important @iainn ? Why do you prefer two separate iterators? (`array_reduce()` and `array_map()`) I feel you have influenced my answer losing the green tick.  `array_unique()` appears to be useless.  My answer only performs one loop in pursuit of directness, efficiency, and code brevity. The temporary keys don't _need_ to be overwritten if inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

The process:

- iterate the array values
- ignore values without permission data
- use module_id values as temporary keys
- determine if each current value is the first occurrence of the module_id or not using `isset()`.
- if 1st, save both values
- if not 1st, append existing permission value with comma and the new permission value.
- when the loop finishes, reindex the result array with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nM5HF))

```
$permissionArr = ["1", "1_3", "1_4", "3", "3_1", "3_2","4", "4_1"];  

foreach($permissionArr as $v) {
    if(strpos($v, "_") !== false) { // logically you could safely omit "!== false" here
        $x = explode("_", $v);
        if (!isset($result[$x[0]])) {
            $result[$x[0]] = ['module_id' => $x[0], 'permission' => $x[1]];
        } else {
            $result[$x[0]]['permission'] .= ",$x[1]";
        }
    }
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'module_id' => '1',
    'permission' => '3,4',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'module_id' => '3',
    'permission' => '1,2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'module_id' => '4',
    'permission' => '1',
  ),
)
```

p.s.  Regarding `stristr()`...

1. You do not need the case-insensitivity that comes from the `i` in the function.
2. The php manual has a note at the `strstr()` page that says when you are merely checking the existence of a substring in a string, `strpos()` is a lighter / more efficient call.

Comment: @sruthy unless you actually need to use the un-imploded values, there is no advantage to looping through the data two times.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm you will get all module with perm. If there will be no permission then you will have an empty array. Its good id you need to test module perm and you will always have module data.

```
// input array
$permissionArr = Array("0" =>1 ,
"1" =>"1_3", 
"2" =>"1_4", 
"3" =>3, 
"4" =>"3_1",
"5" =>"3_2",
"6" =>4,
"7" =>"4_1");

//walk over array and form a new one with module id as key and perm as value array
foreach($permissionArr as $value){
    $data = explode('_',$value);
    $permission = $data[1]??null;
    if($permission){
        $raw[$data[0]][] = $permission;
    }else{
        if(!isset($raw[$data[0]])){
            $raw[$data[0]] = [];
        }
    }
}

// transform new array in desired form 
$result = array_walk($raw, function(&$val, $key){
    $val = ['moduleId' => $key, 'permission' => implode(",",$val)] ;  
}, $raw);

print_r($raw);
```